# Qt signal-slot handling of private variables: feature or flaw?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, private-members

I am working in a rather lengthy c++ code (over 70K lines) using Qt library and came across an unexpected (for me) behavior with the signal-slot mechanism when dealing with private variables.

The idea is that when an object (object1) communicates to another (object2) with a signal including a private variable of the former (vec1 of object1), the latter (object2) is able to modify it. I wonder whether this must be considered as a feature or as a flaw.

I put here a simplified code that illustrates this fact: object1 has a private QVector variable named vec1 (pointer) and sends a signal to object2 for removing some elements of vec1. This object2 catches the signal and carries out the task succesfully.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWin;
    mainWin.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "object1.h"
#include "object2.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{    
    QVector<int> * vec;
    object1 *obj1 = new object1();
    object2 *obj2 = new object2();

    connect(obj1, SIGNAL(remove_items_signal1(QVector<int>*,int)),
        obj2, SLOT(remove_items_slot2(QVector<int>*,int)));

    vec = obj1->get_vec1();

    QString str1("vec1 before removing any elements = ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < vec->length(); i++){
        str1.append(QString(" %1").arg(vec->at(i)));
    }
    QLabel *label1 = new QLabel(str1);

    // remove some elements at the end of the vector using the signal-slot mechanism
    // Notice that the elements of vec1 (which is private of object1) 
    // are removed in object2.

    int i = 3;

    obj1->emit_remove_items(i);

    vec = obj1->get_vec1();

    QString str2("vec1 after removing the last " + QString("%1").arg(i) + " elements in object2 = ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < vec->length(); i++){
        str2.append(QString(" %1").arg(vec->at(i)));
    }
    QLabel *label2 = new QLabel(str2);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(label1);
    layout->addWidget(label2);

    QWidget *window = new QWidget();
    window->setLayout(layout);

    setCentralWidget(window);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

object1.h

```
#ifndef OBJECT1_H
#define OBJECT1_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVector>

class object1 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit object1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~object1();
    void emit_remove_items(int);
    QVector<int> * get_vec1();
signals:
    void remove_items_signal1(QVector<int> *, int);
private:
    QVector<int> *vec1;
};
#endif // OBJECT1_H
```

object1.cpp

```
#include "object1.h"

object1::object1(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    vec1 = new QVector<int>();
    *vec1 << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 8 << 9;
}

object1::~object1(){

}

void object1::emit_remove_items(int i){
    emit remove_items_signal1(vec1, i);
}

QVector<int>* object1::get_vec1(){
    return vec1;
}
```

object2.h

```
#ifndef OBJECT2_H
#define OBJECT2_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVector>

class object2 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit object2(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~object2();
public slots:
    void remove_items_slot2(QVector<int> *, int);
private:
    QVector<int> *vec2;
};
#endif // OBJECT2_H
```

object2.cpp

```
#include "object2.h"

object2::object2(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
   vec2 = new QVector<int>();
}

object2::~object2(){

}

void object2::remove_items_slot2(QVector<int> * vec1, int i){
    vec2 = vec1;
    if (i < vec2->length()){
        int j = vec2->length()-i;
        vec2->remove(j,i);
    }
}
```

Comment: As @rubenvb says: This is not specific to signal/slots, if you pass an object by reference/pointer to another function, the function can modify it. If you don’t want that, don’t pass it to the function/signal. In your example, you access containers via pointer, just don’t do that. Pass them by const reference instead. (they are implicitly shared, so the copies are cheap)

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing weird in the sense that signals/slots are doing something weird. Your member function `object1::emit_remove_items` is passing a reference to the private member `vec1` to the signal `remove_items_signal1` (which is just another function). Connecting this signal to a slot makes the signal implementation call that slot (which is just another function).

Your usage of the signal/slot pattern is a bit weird though, because you give away the private parts of `object1` to `object2`, which as you noticed, breaks encapsulation.

It's good practice to ensure:

1. function names reflect what the functions do, not how they are used when they are first written,
2. signals are named passively, e.g. `somethingChanged`, `somethingEnded`,
3. slots, or all functions really, are actively named, e.g. `doSomething`, `endSomething`.

Applying these guidelines and then altering your code so that thes are fulfilled might even make the weird private pointer passing part go away.
If not, you need to rethink what exactly you are trying to accomplish.